# Animating the drawing of a line in the canvas with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I can draw a line in the canvas using:

```
var myLine = new fabric.Polyline([{x:200,y:200},{x:200,y:200}])
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.add(myLine);
```

However, I want to animate the drawing. I tried:

```
myLine.animate("points","[{x:200,y:200},{x:10,y:10}]",{onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas)})
```

But it's not working, and I couldn't see any way to animate the drawing of the line using fabric.js - I know I can use canvas methods directly but I am curious is fabric.js offers something more concise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvrp63hu/) based on http://fabricjs.com/polygon-animation/ and I change it into a fabricjs `Polyline`. You can set the start and end values from here:

```
var startPoints = [
   {x: 1, y: 1},
   {x: 2, y: 2}
];

var endPoints = [
   {x: 1, y: 1},
   {x: 200, y: 200}
];
```

Comment: Well done, it's exactly what I wanted. It's surprising that fabric.js doesn't provide a function to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No solution suited me so far so here a [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/olafponeta/d34xdg10/) with what i came up with. Its based on the prev solution by Nistor Christian:

I Made a simple function which accepts the Canvas (in case you want to use this on more than one canvas), color, the original Line-Koordinates (StartXY, EndXY) and the new Line-Koordinates (NewStartX,NewStartY).

```
function animateLine(canvasInstance,color,
  startX,startY,endX,endY,
  newStartX, newStartY,newEndX,newEndY)
```